# problem installing mysqlclient in rhel python3.6

Tags: python, airflow, redhat, mysql-python

I'm trying to install apache-airflow[mysql]. Its failing when trying to install the mysqlclient dependency. I'm using rhel7. I have the python-devel and mysql-devel packages installed.

I first tried installing using rh-python36. On reading some issues that it could be with the python environment I compiled another version from source. I also reinstalled mysql.

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/opt/rh/rh-mysql80/root/usr/include/mysql -I/u01/airflow-build-1.0/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -m64
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/opt/rh/rh-mysql80/root/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
```